# Retrieve and concatenate weeks of historical dates

Tags: sql-server, date, formatting, type-conversion, string-concatenation

I have some old excel templates I am trying to replicate, the way they're set up aren't ideal but I using them as an exercise.

In the excel tables there is a column that looks like this:

```
|--Week and dates--|
|------------------|
|Week 291214_040115|
|Week 050115_110115|
|Week 120115_180115|
|...etc............|
|...etc............|
|...etc............|
|...etc............|
|Week 030717_090717|
|Week 100717_160717|
```

With the code below I tried to recreate the above but I have run into several problems.

```
Declare @sDate date,
        @eDate date;

Select  @sDate = '2015-01-01',
        @eDate = '2017-07-31';

;with cte as
(
select @sDate StartDate, 
DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @sDate), 6) EndDate

union all

select dateadd(ww, 1, StartDate),
dateadd(ww, 1, EndDate)

from cte
where dateadd(ww, 1, StartDate)<=  @eDate
)

select concat(StartDate,'_',EndDate) as date

from cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

The output this produces is:

```
|------------Dates-------------|
|2015-01-01_Jan  4 2015 12:00AM|
|2015-01-08_Jan 11 2015 12:00AM|
|2015-01-15_Jan 18 2015 12:00AM|
|2015-01-22_Jan 25 2015 12:00AM|
|2015-01-29_Feb  1 2015 12:00AM|
|2015-02-05_Feb  8 2015 12:00AM|
```

I haven't concatenated the string "week" into the script yet, but basically how to I get the script to look more like the excel template table and less like my own version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your select as below:

```
select concat('Week ',Format(StartDate, 'ddMMyy'),'_',Format(dateadd(day,6,StartDate),'ddMMyy')) as date
   from cte
```